Непонятные символы в "ковычках" по типу char_counts[t.charAt(i) - 'a']
при выполнении разных заданий по java, часто натыкаюсь на решения других людей где они используют условия фильтрации/добавления/удаления чего либо путём написания символа в ковычках по типу 'a' для отслеживания индекса буквы по алфавиту . Я не могу найти как это называется и отсюда не могу изучить принцип работы и найти хоть какую то информацию по этому поводу. вот пример кода в котором я это увидел:
Задание с анаграмами
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char_counts[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++; //Находит индекс буквы в массиве и добовляет туда +1 в данном случае.
            char_counts[t.charAt(i) - 'a']--; //Находит индекс буквы в массиве и отнимает там -1 в данном случае.

Вопрос в целом такой, как это называется? и где можно посмотреть информацию по этим штукам?

Принцип "работы" было бы проще понять, если был бы приведён полный код, но в общем-то он описан во фразе:

либо путём написания символа в ковычках по типу 'a' для отслеживания индекса буквы по алфавиту

В данном случае, в одинарных кавычках записывается английский символ 'a', который вычитается из символа, записанного в строках s и t, чтобы получить корректный индекс в массиве char_counts, назначение которого -- хранить частоты символов в указанных строках.
То есть, конкретно в данной задаче должно быть условие, что строки s, t содержат только строчные английские буквы от 'a' до 'z', и соответственно для корректного вычисления индекса в массиве char_counts для заданной буквы потребуется отнять смещение 'a': 'a' - 'a' -> 0, 'b' - 'a' -> 1, ... 'z' - 'a' -> 25.
Также подразумевается, что строка t НЕ короче строки s.
Такой способ применяется как правило в учебных задачах с ограниченными наборами данных, так как для других символов (хотя бы цифр или прописных букв) индекс будет вычислен неправильно, что приведёт к исключению ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Таким образом, в представленном цикле частоты символов из строки s плюсуются, а из строки t -- минусуются.  Затем проверяется, что было записано в результате в массиве частот char_counts: если найдено хотя бы одно ненулевое значение, строки s и t НЕ являются анаграммами.

Спасибо за ответ, я просто не понимаю сам принцип работы, я эту информацию на "курсах" и
в видео уроках не находил. Я не мог знать о том что такая возможность вообще существует в языке Java. Если я правильно понял, то это работа с Юникодом? как эта операция называется или где можно про это почитать? Я хочу разобраться как это работает и какие ещё варианты подобных "вычислений" есть!

@Corbest Может быть, вас смущает то, что char - это просто двухбайтовое число?

@MBo Нет, меня смущает что я прохожу обучение по языку Java, где внезапно чтоб решить задачу появляется метод о котором я не слышал и не знал и даже не могу предположить как я должен был догадаться что Java может таким образом проводить вычисления(я имею ввиду что можно создать массив пустой на 26 элементов  и в зависимости от символа(в данном случае буквы) в ячейку для элемента которая равна положению по счёту в алфавите будут добавляться или убывать циферки). Я это откуда узнать должен был? я даже не знаю как это называется и где об этом почитать))

Вариант подобных числений указан выше по ссылке для вычисления "числа", представленного строкой, только там берётся числовое значение относительно символа '0'.  В вашем же случае до юникода как такового не доходит, так как фактически используются ASCII-символы.  Более "честный" и безопасный способ подсчёта частоты символов -- использовать словарь/мапу Map<Character, Integer>, см. пример 1, пример 2
